# TRIGGER AFTER UPDATE POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql, set, sql-update

I have the next problem, i tried to set the column n_colaboradores with a trigger's function when i update estado = false to estado = true, but when i do that, n_colaboradores stay on zero and don't increases his value. Something wrong with the trigger sintax or function maybe? help ! :D

```
CREATE TABLE Postula (
id_postulante   int references Postulante(id_postulante) not null,
id_area         int references Area(id_area) not null,
estado          boolean not null,
prioridad       int not null,
primary key(id_postulante, id_area)
);
```

---

```
 CREATE TABLE Area (
id_area         SERIAL primary key not null,
nombreA         varchar(100) not null,
n_colaboradores int not null,
horario         varchar(100) not null,
campusA         varchar(100) not null
 );
```

---

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION AumentarColaboradores()
 RETURNS trigger AS '

 BEGIN

SELECT *FROM AREA a,POSTULA p WHERE a.id_area = p.id_area;

IF (NEW.p.estado IS TRUE)
THEN
    UPDATE AREA
    SET N_COLABORADORES = N_COLABORADORES + 1;
END IF;

END;' LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

---

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trigger_num_seleccionados
        AFTER UPDATE ON POSTULA
        FOR EACH ROW
        EXECUTE PROCEDURE AumentarColaboradores();
```

Comment: I think you want to modify `NEW` in a `BEFORE` trigger instead. Not sure without more explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the `SELECT *FROM AREA a,POSTULA p WHERE a.id_area = p.id_area;` was for in the trigger function but if you just want to update another table on the table being updated where your column "estadio" is true you may only need something as simple as this:

```
create or replace function AumentarColaboradores() returns trigger AS 
$$
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.estado = TRUE) THEN
        UPDATE area
        SET N_COLABORADORES = N_COLABORADORES + 1;
        --no WHERE in this update? it will update the whole table

        -- also, (uncomment below) you may want to take 1 away if estadio is false

--  ELSE
--      UPDATE area
--      SET N_COLABORADORES = N_COLABORADORES - 1;
    END IF;

    RETURN NEW;
END
$$
language plpgsql
```